# Hide ActionBarSherlock title and show only logo

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I need to hide title on ActionBarSherlock and show only logo.

When I use `actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);` icon also hide.

**UPDATE:** Thank you guys, but I found a solution. Question maybe closed

in **styles.xml**:

```
<style name="FooBar" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
         <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FooBar.ActionBar</item>
         <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/FooBar.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FooBar.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
        <item name="displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
    </style>
```

And in **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/FooBar"
    android:allowBackup="true">
```

Comment: `actionBar.setTitle( "" );`

Comment: after hours of frustrations I found your answer helpful :) Thakns man :)

Answer (score 4):

Does

```
actionbar.setTitle("");
```

work?

Comment: Thank you. But not work as I espect. But as I found setIcon(R.drawable.image) work.